# Issue with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When  I tried to read data from a csv file, I got the result that is in a weird format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('HDMA Boston Housing Data.csv')
df
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the first few rows of the csv file?

Comment: hmmm - this doesn't really make sense - pandas should split the data on commas. Is it possible there are weird quotation marks in the file? try opening the file in a text editor to see if there's something strange about the format.

Comment: your file is not exactly comma separated, share few first lines of your csv file exactly as it is ( like when you open it witha a text editor)

Comment: thx guys. I found the same data set that will give me the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be `.txt` file, but renamed and read like a `.csv` file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).